# Compare values in 2D array. Every value to first row

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, compare

Data structure:

[image: Data structure]

I would like to compare every value from 2. row onward to the end, to each value in 1.row. In this example I would like to compare every red-ish value to green, yellow and purple value. The data structure can have more columns and rows, but all values from 2.row onwards are always comparing to the values of firs row.

Example:
I would like to compare all the values to `[75.06176,39.44008]`, `[36.08646,26.384703]` and `[14.038518,55.827003]`.

Number of rows or columns is not fixed.
Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Could you clarify the question, I am not really sure what you're asking to solve?

Comment: Instead of giving such long values first try to build logic with basic one and try to use For loop for iterating values for 2D array.

Comment: @Shams Ansari I edited the question is it more clear now? Check the Data structure picture.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, You want to compare values of one row with another. For that You need 2 for loops for 2D Array.

```
for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<c; j++) {
        if (arr[i][j]>=0)
            System.out.println("Anything you want to print");
}
}
```

Please excuse me if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: No, I would like to compare all the values from 2. row onwards to the each element of first row. Please reed the question again I edited it, so It's maybe more clear.

Comment: I couldn't get what you are looking for. Instead of keeping values that you actually want to operate. Could you please ask me by giving an example of 2D array. It would be helpful by seeing the output that you are expecting.

Comment: Here i made a new question of this, maybe is more clear [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62436112/sorting-2d-array-in-new-2d-array-k-menas-clustering-java].