# Sorting 2D array in new 2D array (K-means clustering)

Tags: java, sorting, multidimensional-array, k-means

As input I have a 2D array `PointXY[][] clusters`, which looks like this:

```
[[23.237633,53.78671], [69.15293,17.138134], [23.558687,45.70517]] . . .
[[47.851738,16.525734], [47.802097,16.689285], [47.946404,16.732542]]
[[47.89601,16.638218], [47.833263,16.478987], [47.88203,16.45793]]
[[47.75438,16.549816], [47.915512,16.506475], [47.768547,16.67624]]
.
.
.
```

So elements in array are of type `PointXY[]` defined like this:

```java
public PointXY(float x, float y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

what I would like to do is sort input clusters and write sorted to array `PointXY[][] clustersSorted` so that each `PointXY` (exept first row) in clusters gets compared to every value of first row.
In other words the elements from the blue set on picture below get compared to every value circled by red.
So I would like to compare each value from 2. Row onwards to every value in first row.

[image: Picture1]

Comparing is done by calling Euclidian function.

```java
public double euclidian(PointXY other) {
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.x - other.x, 2)
            + Math.pow(this.y - other.y, 2));
}
```

Output should be of the same type 2D array but under each red circled point (which stays the same in the same place in output array) should be points from blue part that are closest (by euclidean distance) to the red circled value.

[image: Picture2]

So it's a data structure for K-Means clustering, so that each cluster is a column (circled green) and the first point is a center (circled red) of cluster and all the other points (circled in yellow) in column are points assigned to center.

So the question is how to iterate over input array clusters, compare values as described, and write them into array `clustersSorted`.

I would like to calculate euclidean distance between each point in blue circled set with every value circled in red. And then sort them based on minimal euclidean distance. So in output array `clustersSorted` each point from blue circled set would be under closest point circled in red.

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary float/double array of size [n][(n-1) * n] where input matrix is of the size [n][n-1].

Compute the euclidean distances of all the points in the lower part of the matrix with all the points in the first row and store them at their respective positions in the temporary array.

Create a copy of each temporary sub-array.

Perform any sorting operation on the copy, preferably selection sort as you only need to sort the array partially until the lowest n-1 elements are found.

Finally, create a new output array of size [n][n-1], correspond the lowest euclidean distances to their points, and store the sorted (n-1) element groups of (n-1) points right below their closest reference points.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>See another answer: [Grouping all points starting from the second row by the nearest center point from the first row](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65660628/14940971)</sub>

---

To sort a 2d array of objects by columns, you can first *transpose* this array and sort each row, and then *transpose* it back. To sort a row of elements starting from the second one by the distance from the first one with a custom comparator - you can use [`Arrays.sort(T[],int,int,Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T%5B%5D,int,int,java.util.Comparator)) method:

```java
int m = 4;
int n = 3;
PointXY[][] clusters = {
        {new PointXY(23.237633, 53.78671),
                new PointXY(69.15293, 17.138134),
                new PointXY(23.558687, 45.70517)},
        {new PointXY(47.851738, 16.525734),
                new PointXY(47.802097, 16.689285),
                new PointXY(47.946404, 16.732542)},
        {new PointXY(47.89601, 16.638218),
                new PointXY(47.833263, 16.478987),
                new PointXY(47.88203, 16.45793)},
        {new PointXY(47.75438, 16.549816),
                new PointXY(47.915512, 16.506475),
                new PointXY(47.768547, 16.67624)}};
```

```java
// transpose a matrix
PointXY[][] transposed = new PointXY[n][m];
IntStream.range(0, n).forEach(i ->
        IntStream.range(0, m).forEach(j ->
                transposed[i][j] = clusters[j][i]));
```

```java
// sort each line starting from the second
// element by the distance from the first element
Arrays.stream(transposed).forEach(cluster ->
        Arrays.sort(cluster, 1, cluster.length,
                Comparator.comparingDouble(point ->
                        Math.sqrt(Math.pow(cluster[0].x - point.x, 2)
                                + Math.pow(cluster[0].y - point.y, 2)))));
```

```java
// transpose a matrix back
PointXY[][] clustersSorted = new PointXY[m][n];
IntStream.range(0, m).forEach(i ->
        IntStream.range(0, n).forEach(j ->
                clustersSorted[i][j] = transposed[j][i]));
```

```java
// output
Arrays.stream(clustersSorted).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
```

```
[23.237633,53.78671, 69.15293,17.138134, 23.558687,45.70517]
[47.75438,16.549816, 47.915512,16.506475, 47.768547,16.67624]
[47.89601,16.638218, 47.833263,16.478987, 47.946404,16.732542]
[47.851738,16.525734, 47.802097,16.689285, 47.88203,16.45793]
```

---

Class `PointXY` should look like this:

```java
public class PointXY {
    double x, y;

    public PointXY(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return x + "," + y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<sub>See another answer: [Sorting a 2d array of objects by columns starting from the second row and transposing an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65660055/14940971)</sub>

---

Building sorted cluster. First row are the center points. Other points are grouped by the nearest center. In this case all points are grouped by the second center point:

```java
PointXY[][] clusters = {
        {new PointXY(23.237633, 53.78671),
                new PointXY(69.15293, 17.138134),
                new PointXY(23.558687, 45.70517)},
        {new PointXY(47.851738, 16.525734),
                new PointXY(47.802097, 16.689285),
                new PointXY(47.946404, 16.732542)},
        {new PointXY(47.89601, 16.638218),
                new PointXY(47.833263, 16.478987),
                new PointXY(47.88203, 16.45793)},
        {new PointXY(47.75438, 16.549816),
                new PointXY(47.915512, 16.506475),
                new PointXY(47.768547, 16.67624)}};
```

```java
// array of a center points
PointXY[] centers = clusters[0];

PointXY[][] clustersSorted = Arrays
        // iterate over array of center points
        .stream(centers)
        // for each center point
        .map(center -> Stream.of(center, Arrays
                // iterate over array of clusters starting from the second row
                .stream(clusters, 1, clusters.length)
                // stream over the full array
                .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                // filter nearest points to the current center point
                .filter(point -> Arrays
                        // iterate over array of center points
                        .stream(centers)
                        // sort by euclidean distance from current point
                        .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(centerXY ->
                                Math.sqrt(Math.pow(centerXY.x - point.x, 2)
                                        + Math.pow(centerXY.y - point.y, 2))))
                        // find nearest center point to the current point
                        .findFirst()
                        // check this center point is the current center point
                        .get() == center)
                // array of the nearest points to this center point
                .toArray(PointXY[]::new))
                // center point + array of its nearest points
                .flatMap(element -> element instanceof PointXY ?
                        Stream.of((PointXY) element) :
                        Arrays.stream((PointXY[]) element))
                // sorted cluster
                .toArray(PointXY[]::new))
        // sorted array of clusters
        .toArray(PointXY[][]::new);
```

```java
// output
Arrays.stream(clustersSorted).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
```

```
[23.237633,53.78671]
[69.15293,17.138134, 47.851738,16.525734, 47.802097,16.689285, 47.946404,16.732542, 47.89601,16.638218, 47.833263,16.478987, 47.88203,16.45793, 47.75438,16.549816, 47.915512,16.506475, 47.768547,16.67624]
[23.558687,45.70517]
```

---

Class `PointXY` should look like this:

```java
public static class PointXY {
    double x, y;

    public PointXY(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return x + "," + y;
    }
}
```